# Unable to Run Get-WindowsFeature

Tags: windows-server-2012, powershell

I have a Windows 2012 instance running in the Amazon cloud. It's just a test server for an asp.net project and only has the necessary features installed. The problem is the instances is out of disk space (30 GB). All that's installed is the default stuff and a few things for my asp application. I was looking through some websites like this one, [Free Up Disk Space on Windows Server 2012](http://blogs.technet.com/b/canitpro/archive/2013/11/27/free-up-disk-space-on-windows-server-2012.aspx), and have been trying to remove some unused features from the WinSXS foler (which is over 13.5 GB!). When I try to run Get-WindowsFeature in powershell, the command fails with an error:

> get-windowsfeature : The request to list features available on the
>   specified server failed. A DISM session could not be opened. An error
>   occurred accessing the temporary folder
>   C:\Windows\TEMP\F3023A61-3F1C-4C38-94F5-04C5CA1110CE. Ensure that the
>   path to the temporary folder exists and that you have Read/Write
>   permissions on the folder. Error: 0x80070070 At line:1 char:1
>   + get-windowsfeature
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (@{Vhd=; Credent...Name=localhost}:PSObject) [Get-WindowsFeature], Dep
>   loymentProviderException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DISMAPI_Error__Failed_Opening_Dism_Session,Microsoft.Windows.ServerManager.Commands.GetW
>   indowsFeatureCommand

The folder c:\windows\temp exists and the admin user has access to the folder...
Is this error because I'm out of disk space? What else can I do to free up some space?

Comment: Windows installs are pretty big these days.  You really shouldn't be running with that small of a hard drive.  I believe most would recommend a server start with not less than 100GB.

Comment: Unfortunately I used the default Amazon AMI and, using Amazon's Free Tier, the max size I can get the instance is 30 GB.

Answer (score 1):

Find something else to delete first, like IIS logs.

Answer (score 0):

> What else can I do to free up some space?

Try `Disk Cleanup` first. Here is [how to run it](https://serverfault.com/questions/556613/how-do-i-install-disk-cleanup-on-windows-2012-server-without-installing-the-desk) if you don't have `Desktop Expirience` installed, or don't want to install it.

To run Disk cleanup:

1. Click <kbd>Start</kbd>
2. Click <kbd>All Programs</kbd> → <kbd>Accessories</kbd> → <kbd>System Tools</kbd> → <kbd>Disk Cleanup</kbd>
3. Select <kbd>Drive C</kbd> from the drop-down menu
4. Click <kbd>OK</kbd>